# Kotlin merge function

Tags: function, kotlin

My goal is to have function which merge N functions into one. Preferably with inlining.

I see it like:

```
inline fun merge(vararg functions:(N)->Unit):(N)->Unit{
//something that makes this vararg into one function which calls all functions from vararg is sequence
}
```

How can i do it? If I can.

Comment: You simply have to return a `(N) -> Unit` that loops over the `functions` array and invokes each function with the given argument. I don't believe making `merge` an inline function will provide any benefit here, however.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
fun <N> merge(vararg functions: (N) -> Unit): (N) -> Unit = { n: N ->
    functions.forEach { it(n) } 
}
```

Example of usage:

```
val one: (Int) -> Unit = { it + 2 }
val two: (Int) -> Unit = { it + 5 }

merge(one, two)(5)
```

Comment: Thats tottaly work, but not exactly what i wanna to achieve. My goal was to merge argument function into one. Something like this:
merge ({println("first")},{println("second")}) =
{
println("first");
println("second")
}

Comment: @Brengar It does merge in the way you want to achieve. You can try to write `merge({println("first")}, {println("second")})` and see if the function works as you expected.